# Launch n times a Launch Configuration C/C++

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, launch-configuration

I need to launch n times a specific Launch Configurations C/C++ defined by the user, where i change every time the binary executed. How can i do this programmatically? It is possible? I think that it's possible to create n different Run Configuration, starting from originary one,  each of which contains different binary and then use Launch Group to launch each run configuration. But i need a sort of External Tool that use a defined Run Configuration from user and then run it n times.
The user can make only a C/C++ project e build it and obviously Run it. He have not to specify parameter n: the number of iteration is decided by me based on some informations.

Comment: How do the user specify `n`? Who is the user?

Comment: The user can make only a C/C++ project e build it and obviously Run it. He have not to specify parameter n: the number of iteration is decided by me based on some informations.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. Export the launch configuration you want to invoke n times using File->Export wizard and select Run/Debug->Launch configuration
2. Develop a plug-in which asks the user to enter number of times to launch and the launch configuration file to select. You have create a dialog here which imports the launch configuration files exported in step 1.
3. Parse the launch configuration files (these are in xml format) and prepare the object of type `ILaunchConfiguration` and try to invoke the code below(This was copied from `org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog#handleLaunchPressed()`)

   ```
   ILaunchConfiguration config = fTabViewer.getOriginal();
   if (fTabViewer.isDirty() && fTabViewer.canSave()) {
       config = fTabViewer.handleApplyPressed();
   }
   if(config != null) {
       close();
       DebugUITools.launch(config, getMode());
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks for the answer. practically i don't need to interact with eclipse gui but launch this configuration n times automatically....what changes is the binary that is executed

Comment: You can keep on pressing Ctrl + F11 **n** times